# How do you find the derivative of $y=\mathrm{arcsech}(e^{-x})$?

Tags: derivatives, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-function

**Problem**

Given $y=\mathrm{arcsech}(e^{-x})$ , find the derivative.

**My work**

let $x=e^{-x}$ so

$y=\mathrm{arcsech}(x)$

$x=\mathrm{sech}(y)$

I then differentiated implicitly which gave me

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\mathrm{\frac{1}{{-sech}(y){tanh}(y)}}$

I built a right angle triangle with the sides c=x a=$\sqrt{{x^2}{-1}}$ b=1 from the equation $x=\mathrm{sech}(y)$

Using the right angle triangle, I came up with the following ratios

$\mathrm{sech}(y)=\frac{x}{1}$

$\mathrm{tanh}(y)=\frac{\sqrt{{x^2}{-1}}}{{1}}$

Substituting the new equations into the derivative gives me

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\mathrm{\frac{1}{{-x}{\sqrt{{x^2}{-1}}}}}$

Since $x=e^{-x}$, then

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\mathrm{\frac{-1}{{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{{e^{-2x}}{-1}}}}}$

Because this also involves the chain rule, I differentiated

$y=\mathrm{e^{-x}}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\mathrm{-e^{-x}}$

So

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\mathrm{\frac{-1}{{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{{e^{-2x}}{-1}}}}}\times\mathrm{-e^{-x}}$

I then concluded that

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{{e^{-2x}}{-1}}}$

The answer states

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{{1-}{e^{-2x}}}}$

Not sure how to fix my error.

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for MathJax hints.  The use of backticks and indentation will break it.

Comment: It would help if you would show how you got the answer you did - then it will probably be easy for someone to spot the error.

Comment: @user377120 You see $\tanh^2(x)+\text{ sech}^2(x)=1$. Therefore, $\tanh^2(x) = 1-x^2$, not $x^2-1$.